# Annotate returning individual elements rather than grouping

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Here are my models:

```
    class Submission(models.Model):
         user = models.ForeignKey(to=DefaultUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
         total_score = models.DecimalField()
```

Now I want to get the count of submissions for each user
And here is the query that I am trying

> Submission.objects.values('user').annotate(Count('id'))

And the output is:

```
     {'user': 1, 'id__count': 1}
     {'user': 1, 'id__count': 1}
     {'user': 1, 'id__count': 1}
     {'user': 1, 'id__count': 1}
     {'user': 2, 'id__count': 1}
     {'user': 2, 'id__count': 1}
     {'user': 3, 'id__count': 1}
```

Whereas the output that I require is:

```
     {'user': 1, 'id__count': 4}
     {'user': 2, 'id__count': 2}
     {'user': 3, 'id__count': 1}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an [**`.order_by`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) to force the `QuerySet` to "fold":

```
Submission.objects.values('user').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('user')
```

This behavior is documented in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by):

> (...)
>
> Fields that are mentioned in the `order_by()` part of a queryset (or
>   which are used in the default ordering on a model) are used when
>   selecting the output data, even if they are not otherwise specified in
>   the `values()` call. **These extra fields are used to group "like"
>   results together** and they can make otherwise identical result rows
>   appear to be separate.
>
> (...)

Note that since [django-3.1](/questions/tagged/django-3.1), the "*default ordering on a model*" will no longer be used.